# Xcode 11.1 not installing new build with changes (iOS 13.1.2)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

After installing 11.1 I created a new project, removed the multi-window stuff that Xcode now gives you by default, and started developing a test app that uses Vision Framework.

By the time I got to the point where I needed to test on the device instead of the simulator, I was struggling to make my app work correctly. I finally realized that running the app on my phone required me to delete the app and run a fresh install or the changes wouldn't be pushed to the device. This continues to be a problem. Even a new print statement won't be shown in the debugger output unless I go through the rigamarole of deleting the app and running fresh. Subsequent changes still use the initially installed build regardless of the number of times I clean/build/run.

I've cleaned the project, build folder, derived data, Xcode cache, rebooted my Mac, rebooted my phone, reinstalled Xcode, obliterated and reinstalled Xcode again, all with no success.

Anyone else with this issue? What am I missing?!

Comment: I like the word "rigamarole".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, after two days of trying to fix this, it turns out to be some kind of Apple bug on iOS 13 (surprise, surprise).

Here's what I did/found:

- I tried running on another device and was able to see changes on subsequent runs.
- Back on the original test device, the issue still exists (Xcode issue ruled out)
- I had a couple other test apps that were signed with the same development cert on the device, so I deleted those too.
- Running the app from Xcode again prompted me to go to settings to trust the developer certificate
- Changes and updates are now pushed to the device on each run from Xcode.

TLDR:

If you happen to run into a similar issue, try deleting other development certificate apps you have on your device and re-trust the certificate.